# Modern OpenGL - how to render VBO part in different color

Tags: opengl, glsl, vbo

I have big VBO (100k+ triangles) with assigned colors (x,y,z,r,g,b) and I would like to render a few selected triangles in different color (for example, render in white triangles 10000-10007). Rendering only mentioned part of VBO isnt a problem but it would get rendered in original color. 
Few solutions comes to my mind but they all sound VERY stupid:

- Change the VBO part. Too much work and certainly not efficient (I would have to read and re-interpret bytes, store them, override, render and restore)
- Add new uniform selectedColor and check in each fragment if it is not black (usless condition executed 100k times)
- As above but add whole new shader just for this simple task, avoiding condition (with so many shaders one will get lost soon)

Any idea how achieve so "simple" task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just *adjust* your current shader. Just add a uniform variable for the color, and upload a new value when rendering the highlighted part of the VBO.

If your not-highlighted part of the VBO uses some computation to get the color, you might want to think of a way to incorporate the uniform such that it has an "identity" value. Meaning if you put in said identity value, you'd get the original color. An **example** would be to multiply the computed color by the alpha component of the uniform, then add the rgb part of the uniform: `computedColor * uniform.a + uniform.rgb`. If you put in the value `(0,0,0,1)` you'd get the computedColor. If you put in the value `(r,g,b,0)`, you'd get the uniform color, and you can even 'blend' the two.

About the other suggested solutions. Editing the VBO indeed sounds stupid, I'd only ever do that if your data dynamically changes, for things like soft meshes or maybe particles, but even then there's probably a better way using transform feedbacks. Similar to my suggestion, but not quite, adding a new shader sounds unnecessary. The context switch of making the new program active is rather expensive, probably more so than the simple uniform example I suggested above (very *very* probably).

My point being that another solution would be to find some mathematical formula so you exploit it to behave like both the computed color and your replacement color (or replacement formula). This would eliminate the need to put in expensive branches or such in your shaders. Nor would you need to do expensive buffer editing or program switching.

Comment: Very clever, didnt thought of that. Any ideas where could I find resources comparing costs? I mean 3 multiplication can be less/more expensive than one branch or shader switch is more then 100k branches? (roughly ofcourse)

Comment: Basically this: Assume switching programs is expensive as crap, avoid it unless your shader is doing lots of memory accesses and such (texture lookups or similar). Basic arithmetic computations are _VERY_ fast and branching _can_ be very expensive, but doesn't have to be. If you want to decide whether branching is worth it or not read this as a start:
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter34.html

Also, profile!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally I would draw another polygon over the selected ones, in this case you can even put some blending in it to give a better effect.

Comment: Can you specify how? Drawing part of VBO isnt a problem - but changing color of it is. (do you recommond the 3rd option, add new shader ignoring the original color and using uniform instead?)

Comment: Render the entire object you want to highlight some triangles, then render another VBO with just the selected triangles but another color. You can even use the same shader.

Comment: @wondra I think the best here would be a new shader with a uniform color. Having another VBO in memory looks like a waste to me.

Comment: @greenboxal copy the selected part, edit it and then render as another VBO, did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also generate a small 1D texture and send in one texture coordinate per vertex. Then you can change the texture data to modify the colors.

Depends how much control you need i guess.